# How to select object with underscore or braces from HTTP Response?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, httpresponse, vuejs3

I can select the `heading` object of this `http response`:

```
{data: Array(1), status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
  data: Array(1)
    0:
      heading: "Hello World"
```

like this:

```
axios.get('/home')
    .then(res => {
        const $heading = res.data.heading;
    }
```

How would I select the `heading` object but for this `http response`:

```
{data: Array(1), status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
  data: Array(1)
    0:
      heading_(en): "Hello World"
```

These attempts produce errors:

```
const $heading = res.data.heading_(en);
const $heading = res.data['heading_(en)'];
```

The same thing happens, when I try to select a `response` with:

```
heading_en: "Hello World"
```

by running:

```
const $heading = res.data.heading_en;
```

Comment: isn't data an Array with 1 element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get it, use
`res.data[0]['heading_en']`